# I have a query that finds duplicates in my SQL database-now how do I delete said duplicates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an sql query that finds and groups these duplicates using very complicated conditions:

```
SELECT right(post_url, LOCATE('-', REVERSE(post_url),LOCATE('-',REVERSE(post_url))+1) -1) as name,
left(post_name,LOCATE('-',post_url,LOCATE('-',post_url)+1) - 1) as city,
post_title as original,ID,post_name,count(*) 
FROM table WHERE post_type='finder' 
GROUP BY name,city having count(*) > 1
```

To explain the query, post_url is basically a url name, ending with the name of someone, e.g : new-jersey-something-something-donald-t

I go to the second dash from the right and get the name that way. Then I get the city/state which is in the second dash from the left. In this manner, I've successfully found the duplicates in this database-but I'm having trouble thinking of a way to isolate the duplicate and delete it. In addition, I only want to delete the copy that does *not* have %near% in post_url. my question is, using the query here, how would I change this to delete the duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to do it in one query. That's because you need to write a query that looks something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT ... FROM table WHERE ...)
```

MySQL specifically prohibits this. You can't delete based on a subquery that references the same table. You also can't rewrite this query using `JOIN`s.

There is an easy solution, though: use a temporary table and two queries.

```
-- build the list of IDs to delete
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp
SELECT ... FROM table WHERE ...

-- now delete those items
DELETE FROM table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp);
```

You can improve performance with `JOIN`s and indexes.

The key to "isolating" the duplicates is to ensure that every item you want to delete has a primary key - that way you can easily build a list of IDs to delete. If your table don't have primary keys, you are reduced to doing `WHERE` clauses and `JOIN`s on multiple columns - that gets messy very quickly.

Comment: This is good information, thanks! Would you happen to know how to isolate the duplicate copies using the query I have now?